# Why do different buttons get same ID?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Good day everyone,

I am writing my code in Kotlin and trying to get different response from the two different buttons:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_choice)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    mVisible = true

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.


    val btnCN = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.custom_button_cn)
    val btnUK = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.custom_button_uk)


    btnCN.setOnClickListener(this)
    btnUK.setOnClickListener(this)

    println(this)
    println(btnCN)
    println(btnUK)
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when(v?.id){
        R.id.custom_button_cn -> {
            println("CHINESE")
            println(v)
        }
        R.id.custom_button_uk -> {
            println("ENGLISH")
            println(v)
        }

        else -> {
            println("ELSE!!!")
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am doing somewhat wrong. As in the log I get the following:

```
05-16 23:04:17.884 8674-8674/com.example.user.app I/System.out: ENGLISH
    android.widget.LinearLayout{409e926 VFE...C.. ...P.... 0,0-1050,1050 #7f080035 app:id/custom_button_uk}
05-16 23:04:24.023 8674-8674/com.example.user.app I/System.out: ENGLISH
    android.widget.LinearLayout{409e926 VFE...C.. ...P.... 0,0-1050,1050 #7f080035 app:id/custom_button_uk}
05-16 23:04:27.771 8674-8674/com.example.user.app I/System.out: ENGLISH
    android.widget.LinearLayout{409e926 VFE...C.. ...P.... 0,0-1050,1050 #7f080035 app:id/custom_button_uk}
```

Here is how I have created the buttons:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id = "@+id/rel_lay"
        android:layout_width="1280dp"
        android:layout_height="1280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35pt"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_button_cn"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/china_button_drawable" >

            <!-- Image (BG IMG) -->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_cn" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_button_uk"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/uk_button_drawable" >

            <!-- Image UK -->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_en" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have already checked the code and couldn't find any errors, but I guess I miss some sort of Kotlin trick. For the sake of tests, I have tried to remove the images, added IDs to the images, tried to access layer by layer, for instance giving the id to the relative layout, than to the linear and finally to the image and so accessing the inner thing. Nonetheless it didn't work. Can you please explain what is the right way to address to the button and get the corresponding activity for each of them?

Comment: But you have an `onClick` set on a layout not on a button, is that what you want?

Comment: @LieForBananas he is using layout as buttons.. check his xml

Comment: @Anna, I think there is a thing called **Image Buttons** btw.. why use linear layout as button?

Comment: @Sam. I know what the XML looks like, I asked the question to clarify the situation and not to point out something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `RelativeLayout`, children are laid out on top of each other in order of declaration unless constrained otherwise by layout constraints. Your CN and UK button layouts have no layout constraints so the UK button layout is on top of the CN layout, and since it covers the underlying layout fully, only it can receive clicks.

You can make the buttons next to each other by adding corresponding constraints to the layout. For example, `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/custom_button_cn"` to `custom_button_uk`, or changing the parent `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your layout is ok (ref @laalto's answer), try to use anonymous listeners like so:

```
    btnCN.setOnClickListener { println("CHINESE") }
    btnUK.setOnClickListener { println("ENGLISH") }
```